# Which fruit fall onto my house?

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, vectors

I am following a question on a programming challenge website ([here's the original reference](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/apple-and-orange/problem)). What I have is a **house** (start & endpoint) and some types of **trees** at their respective location points. Each of these trees produce some **fruits** that would fall at different **distances**. My job is to find if the fruits have fallen on the house area (inside of start & endpoint). Illustration :

[image]

Instead of `cin` everything into a single var according to the picture, I want to make my code more dynamic, therefore I decided to use vector structure :

```
house     = location point of house (start & endpoint)
trees     = location point of each tree
fruits    = number of fruits fall
fruit     = distance of each fallen fruit
counting  = number of fruits fall inside the house area
```

**Constraints** :

```
1 <= house, trees, fruits, distance <= 10^5
-10^5 <= distance <= 10^5
a < s < t < b (following the picture)
```

**Input Format** :

```
Sample Input :
7 11      // house location
5 15      // tree location
3 2       // how many fruits fall from each tree
-2 2 1    // distance of 3 fruits fell from tree A
5 -6      // distance of 2 fruits fell from tree A

Sample Output :
1         // tree loc = 5 , fruits loc : -2 2 1. So, (5-2=3) (5+2=7 -- inside house!) (5+1 =6)
1         // tree loc = 15, fruits loc : 5 -6.   So, (15+5=20) (15-6=9 -- inside house!)
```

My code works on a several test cases, and failed some cases including [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nowhere-girl/fd137266cdd5fc06911573656b0eb18c/raw/d25872f90f7bdf4beb2970a02a190b6e19184625/Test%2520Case%25201) and [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nowhere-girl/8dcde791cd3e58e4a584e8765eddae26/raw/1c7fd1263021298a22780250a08f2195b4bf8375/Test%2520Case%25202). Any improvement I can do with my code or advice on better approach ? Here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::getline;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::istringstream;

vector<int> house;            // location point of house (start & endpoint)
vector<int> trees;            // location point of each trees
vector<int> fruits;           // number of fruits fall
vector<vector <int>> fruit;   // distance of each fallen fruits
vector<int> counting;         // number of fruits fall inside house area

istringstream iss;
string line;
int data  = 0; 
int count = 0;
double powerup   = pow(10, 5);  
double powerdown = -powerup;  
    
void reset(){
    iss.clear(); 
    iss.seekg(0); 
    line.clear();
    data = 0;
}

int input(vector<int>& input){                                                         
    getline(cin, line);
    iss.str(line);  
    while (iss >> data){
        // constraint : 1 <= house, trees, fruits, distance <= 10^5
        if ((data >= 1) && (data <=  powerup)){                                                      
            input.push_back(data);
        } else { 
            cout << "input is less than 1 or bigger than 10^5"; 
            return 1; }                   
    }
    return 0; 
}
 
int input_tree(vector<int>& input,vector<int>& house){                                                         
    getline(cin, line);
    iss.str(line);  
    while (iss >> data){
        // constraints : 1 <= trees <= 10^5 & tree can't be inside the house area (a <s <t <b)
        if (((data < house[0]) || (data >  house[1])) && ((data >= 1) && (data <=  powerup))){                                                      
            input.push_back(data);
        } else { 
            cout << "Tree can't be inside the house area !"; 
            return 1; }                   
    }
    return 0; 
}

void print(vector<int>& input){
    int length = input.size();
    for (int i =0; i < length; i++){
            cout << "Input " << input[i] << " ";
    }
        cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    input(house);
    //print(house);
    
    reset();
    input_tree(trees, house);
    //print(trees);

    reset();
    input(fruits);
    //print(fruits);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < fruits.size(); i++){
        reset();
        fruit.push_back(vector<int>());
        getline(cin, line);
        iss.str(line);  
        for (int j = 0; j < fruits[i]; j++){
            while (iss >> data){ 
                // constraints : -10^5  <= distances <= 10^5 
                if ((data >= powerdown) && (data <=  powerup)){ 
                    fruit[i].push_back(data);
                    // if a fruit has fallen on the house, count++
                    if ((trees[0] + data >= house[i]) && (trees[i] + data <= house[1])) count++;
                } else { 
                    cout << "input is less than -10^5 or bigger than 10^5"; 
                    return 1; }   
            } 
        }       
        counting.push_back(count);
    } 

    // print out numbers of fruits of each tree fall inside the house area
    for (int i = 0; i < counting.size(); i++){
        cout << counting[i] << endl;
    }
  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `house[i]` using index of... `fruits` is confusing (it appears that both have size 2). but `house` should not be a `std::vector`, `std::array<int, 2>`/`std::pair<int, int>` or even better `struct House { int begin; int end; };` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things I like:

- You divided the problem into sensible-sized functions (perhaps `input()` could be renamed to something like `input_house()` or something to make its purpose clearer).

Style that I dislike:

- We shouldn't need all those `using` statements at global scope.  But at least you have controlled which names you've brought in, and not used the whole `std` namespace as some beginners do!
- The names `powerup` and `powerdown` aren't very meaningful to me.  I think `counting` could be better, too.

Some points for improvement:

- We don't need all those global variables.  For instance, `line` isn't persistent state, so each function can have its own short-lived `line`, `data`, etc.
- Error messages should go to `std::cerr` rather than `std::cout`.
- The various `input` functions return values, but we ignore them.
- We refer to `std::pow` as plain `pow`, even though we have no `using` for that, which isn't portable (C++ implementations are allowed but not required to define the global-namespace version).  I don't think we need this function (or any of `<cmath>`), though, as we're just using it to create a constant which can be an integer:

  ```
    const double powerup = 10'000;
  ```
- We don't need to use `std::endl` anywhere here - ordinary newline (`\n`) will be fine, and we can leave the stream to be flushed when it's closed as the program ends.
- `std::vector::size()` returns a `std::size_t`, so don't assign to an `int` variable or compare against signed values:

  ```
    std::size_t length = input.size();  // or better: auto length =

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < counting.size(); i++){
  ```

  In this last case, we don't use `i` within the loop, so we can use *range-based `for`*:

  ```
    for (auto value: counting){
        std::cout << value << `n`;
    }
  ```